# Dirvish backup and SSH-connection abort after connection is established

Tags: debian, ssh, rsync, backup

I'm new to Unix & Linux Stackexchange.
I have to following problem: I want to backup a virtual machine ruinning Debian 12 with dirvish on Debian 12. But when the dirvish machine connects to the virtual machine for backing it up, it asks me 6 times for the password and after that it says broken pipe:

```
$ sudo dirvish --vault VMRoot --init
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    msi19@192.168.123.456's password:
    dirvish VMRoot:default error (12) -- broken pipe
    dirvish error: branch /backup/dirvish/VM/VMRoot:default image 20230814 failed
```

When I try to connect via ssh with `$ ssh msi19@192.168.123.456` it works fine with no errors or problems. Does anyone know, why I get this error?

Kind regards,
msi19

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that problem is, that some versions of sshd on older systems are too old to work with debian 12 ssh-version. With newer versions, even and above debian 10 it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).